# Don't display list after form submit

Tags: infopath, list-form, display-form

I have a SharePoint list with an InfoPath form to submit data. When the InfoPath form is submitted, I have it set to close the form. However, it displays the list when the form is closed. How do I

Answer (score 1):

You can append the url that opens the form with &Source=http://somewhere.com, then after submission user will be re-directed to where source is pointing to.